# How to serve file with static resources on all routes in Express JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

How to serve file with static resources on all routes in Express JS?

I tried serving file with static resources using these line of codes,

```
app.use(Express.static(`${this.PATH}`));
app.use(Cors());
app.use(Express.json()); 
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile('./index.html',{root: path});
});
```

If the user visit route 'localhost/test', response is the index.html file. Then main.js is fetched also.

So this first part is working. However, if the user visit route 'localhost/test/testing', response is the index.html file but the main.js is not fetched correctly. The content of main.js is index.html that makes it result to `"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'"`

Comment: Probably you need to change the path on `main.js` inside your `index.html` file to be `/main.js`, not just `main.js`.  Without the leading `/`, then the browser adds the path of the HTML file to the request and that makes it so that when the page is `/test/testing`, then the browser will request `/test/testing/main.js` and `express.static()` won't find it because that's not where `main.js` is.  Show us the HTML for `index.html` if you want further help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the most likely possibility is that you need to change the `<script>` tag in `index.html` from this:

```
<script src="main.js"></script>
```

to this:

```
<script src="/main.js"></script>
```

---

When you enter `/test/testing` in the URL bar, the browser will request that file from your server.  Your server will send back `index.html`.  Then, the browser will parse that file and see the request from this tag:

```
<script src="main.js"></script>
```

Since there is no path on the file being requested, the browser will add the path of the current page to that file before it sends the request to the web server.  That means, it will send a request for:

```
/test/testing/main.js
```

to your web server.  But, your `express.static()` route won't find a file that matches that path.  Therefore, it will fall through to your  `res.sendFile('./index.html',{root: path});` and the browser will get an HTML file when it's expecting a Javascript file and will thus give you the error you report.

I'm personally not a fan of catch all routes like you have that send `index.html` for anything that doesn't match something else because it can lead to very confusing bugs or problems, but if you do so, you HAVE to not use relative paths with any of your URLs in your page because they will all break when someone requests something like `/test/testing`.

Comment: It works! I catch all routes so that my frontend Framework (ReactJS) will handle all the rendering of pages.

Comment: @JMA - Well, the catch all leads to problems for things you DO want your server to handle like this.  Anyway, glad this fixed it.  You will have to avoid ALL relative paths if you want to program this way.